# Code composer studio project - does not create and cannot find .out file

Tags: c, file, build, loading, code-composer

I am making projects on code composer studio for an assignment, using the following setting:

[image: CCStudio settings image]

I have created build variables for the libraries being used in the code.

I connected my board to debug and run the program.  It complains of an error where it cannot load the .out file for the project folder.   When I look in the project, specifically the Debug folder, there is no .out file for that folder.

I am getting the following error message (lab22 is the name of the project folder).

CORTEX_M4_0: GEL: Encountered a problem loading file: C:\Users\geniu\OneDrive\GW\Fall 2023\ECE-6140\Lab3\Debug\Lab3.out Could not open file

Here are the first few lines of the code.

```
       #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
    #include "inc/hw_types.h"
    #include "inc/hw_sysctl.h"
    #include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
    #include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
    #include "driverlib/gpio.h"
    int main(void)
    {
       // clock rpogramming
       // Main Crystal Oscillator = 16 MHzPLL generates 400 MHz from 16 MHz
      // Default /2 divider in the clock path
      //Specifying another /5
      //System (CPU) Clock Frequency
      // 400 MHz/10 = 40 MHz

   SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);
```